# EF6 Tries To Create Tables at Runtime, but No Pending Changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6.1.3 Code First Migrations for my ASP.NET project. I have disabled automatic migrations. I ran the `Add-Migration` and the `Update-Database` commands, an EF can't find any pending changes between the `__MigrationHistory` and the `DbContext`. However, when I start the application, it tries to create the tables from the context, if if they are already present in the latest entry in the `__MigrationHistory` table. (I examined the EDMX XML file from the migrations table, just to be sure). Do you have any ideas, how I can fix this, without losing any data?
[image: tes]
[image: test]
[image: test]

Comment: Sounds like your migrations may be out of sync. You can either locate the migration that is trying to create 'City' table and comment out all that code for existing tables and apply it with update-database, or you can just create a new baseline migration ( Add-Migration InitialCreate –IgnoreChanges) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn579398.aspx#option1

Comment: I see in your comments below you have a separate context for Identity. Make sure you are targeting the correct context for migrations (-ContextTypeName) or make you app context inherit from the IdentityDbContext.

Comment: Yeah, I already double and triple checked that. The problem was that I had not set up the property `MigrationsNamespace` in the `DbMigrationsConfiguration`, and it was causing the other `DbContext` to be migrated with the wrong migrations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want your application to always re-create the tables at runtime, you have to change the database initializer. In your `DBContext` class, you should see some code like this (assuming your `DBContext` is called `MyDbContext`):

```
static MyDbContext()
{
    // You should see this...
    Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyDbContext>());
    // ... or this ...
    Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyDbContext>());
}
```

The first initializer will always recreate your database, and the second initializer will only recreate your database if the model has changed. If no initializer is specified, the default is `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` which, as the name suggests, will create the database if it doesn't already exists. You can alternatively set the initializer in your configuration file. See [this resource](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx) for more examples and information.

Comment: I have this piece of code in my context `OnModelCreating` method `Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ContentDbContext, Configuration>());` Should I remove it?

Comment: Is that the only location where you see an initializer being set? Run a search for `SetInitializer` to see if it pops up anywhere else.

Comment: I have it in another `DbContext` and I need it there, because for that context I have automatic migrations enabled (it is the context for the ASP.NET Identity Framework). Is this not going to kill my automatic migrations? If I remove it even from there, EF does not try to recreate the DB anymore, but is this the right way to go around it?

Comment: The initializer for your identity context should be fine, I was just checking to see if a second initializer was being set on `ContextDbContext`. If you are just debugging and working on a personal project, and you don't mind if the database is dropped each run, using the `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` initializer is the easiest. Since you have disabled automatic migrations and are doing migrations manually, `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` no longer makes sense.

Comment: I see, but as I said I have another `DbContext`, this from the ASP.NET Identity Framework. So for that context I need a `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` initializer, but if I add it, the app keeps crashing for no reason, since this other context should not affect the `ContentDbContext`.

Comment: The identity context initializer probably shouldn't be `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` since the user tables rarely change. I would remove that one completely, and make the initializer for your other context `DropCreateDatabaseAlways`.

Comment: Well, this would wipe out all of the users (since they are stored in the identity context) each and every time, or am I something here?

Comment: If you delete the identity context initializer, it will default to `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`, which will only create the tables if the database has been wiped. The existing user tables will be unaffected.